# Does Windows assembly not exist in the mono for Android profile?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am developing a sample Xamarin application and i got a build error for Android profile,following is the error.

```
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.
Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name: 'Windows.dll'    at 
Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()
```

I couldn't understand what is the exact problem,is windows assembly is not exist in the mono for Android profile? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can see all the available assemblies here:

Xamarin.Android: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/assemblies

Xamarin.iOS: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/assemblies

So no Windows.dll is not available. You can also scan your current assemblies for compatibility here: http://scan.xamarin.com/

Answer (score -1):

there should be updates available in your android sdk.